# Spring MVC Populate object by Converter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have controller method which handle requests of 2 types: adding new `Group` and editing existing `Group`. Before I used method with `@ModelAttribute` annotation to populate `Group`:

```
@ModelAttribute("group")
public Group setGroup(Long id) {
    if (id != null) {
        return groupService.read(id);
    } else {
        return new Group();
    }
}
```

Now I want to use `ConvertionService` to populate object. I've written `GroupConverter` and configured it. But I can not get it to work.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
@RequestMapping("/edit")
public ModelAndView addAndEditGroup(Group group) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("groups/edit");
    modelAndView.addObject("specialties", specialtyService.list()).addObject("group", group);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

(this doesn't work with editing - it only populates `id` field)

```
@RequestMapping("/edit")
public ModelAndView addAndEditGroup(@RequestParam("id") Group group) {
    // same code
}
```

(this doesn't work with adding - it says request parameter `id` not found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with providing default `@RequestParam` value, e.g:

```
@RequestParam(value = "id", defaultValue = "0")
```

Doing so you would just need to check if value is `0` instead of `null`.

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted